# Flutter - How do you make dynamic content (inside navigator) in expanded scrollable?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The layout is:

- Scaffold

  - Column

    - Expanded

      - Navigator
    - Container

However, when the page loaded in navigator is long, it overflows with the yellow and black warning.

Please, let me know how to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: can you put a sketch of the requirement

Comment: if you are fine with scroll then wrap the column inside `SingleChildScrollView` or update the question with some more details like image or Navigator page code etc